# Why is Const able to be called outside of its block scope?

Tags: javascript, syntax

Why does calling const allowed in the following instance.

```
const pizza = {

    topping1: "ham",
    topping2: "pepperoni"

}

console.log(pizza.topping2);
```

technically "pizza.topping2" is outside of the curly braces. So why does it work? I figured you have to call the const somehow, however, lessons on const, state its used as a block level variable only. This might seem like a novice question( it is) however its important for me to understand the logic behind writing the syntax.

Comment: You have assigned an object to pizza using object literal. here `{}` are not making any scope

Comment: those curly braces don't define a scope here, they initialize an object...

Comment: gotcha ok. so what defines something as a block, as opposed to it being global? from my reading thus far, blocks have always been identified as code in-between curly braces.

Comment: Thank you, I don't see how you're supposed to learn if you don't ask questions you can't wrap your head around, the answer from Luca, literally changed my perspective.

Comment: IMO one should learn about the language with lessons and tutorials (there are plenty), not by simply asking question on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Jay don't be discouraged. This site can be tremendously useful but there are a lot of people here who feel they have something to prove. However there are lots of folks who are happy to help. So long as your question is focussed and clear (this one is) and you explain that you've thought it through, then it's a good question for SO. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

In the current example the curly braces `{}` are not creating a block scope. Its just used as [**Object initializer**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

> Objects can be initialized using new `Object()`, `Object.create()`, or using the literal notation (initializer notation). An object initializer is a comma-delimited list of zero or more pairs of property names and associated values of an object, enclosed in curly braces (`{}`).

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block)

> A **block** statement (or compound statement in other languages) is used to group zero or more statements. The block is delimited by a pair of curly brackets and may optionally be labelled

**Syntax**:

```
{
  StatementList
}
```

The following snippet will throw error

```js
{
  const x = 3;
}
console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to `console.log` is in the same lexical scope as `pizza`.

You can think of it like this:

```
{
    const pizza = { ... };
    console.log(pizza.topping1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript uses `{ ... }` with two different meanings:

In an *expression context* those brackets are an object literal, used to create an object based of key-value pairs.

In a *statement context* they are used to create a block scope, which is a list of statements that are then run in their own scope.

```
 /* statement context */

 const variable = /*expression context */;

 test(/*expression context*/)
```

In your case it is an object literal, the `const` declaration is therefore in the global scppe, no other scope gets created.